# Is it normal to have a *-config binary to output installation paths?

Tags: makefile, configuration

I am building the library [AqBanking and Gwenhywfar](https://www.aquamaniac.de/).

I first configured Gwenhywfar to with a prefix (`./configure --prefix=/gwen`) and realized, when building AqBanking, that I can not change the path `/gwen` to something else, because in the `configure` of AqBanking, it uses the tool `gwenhywfar-config` to configure the paths to the library:

```
gwenhywfar_libs="`$gwenhywfar_dir/bin/gwenhywfar-config --libraries`"
```

Now I was wondering

1. Is this a common approach? And if yes: Why?
2. Is there a way to move my library safely after it was built?

Comment: Are you sure `gwenhywfar-config` is actually a binary, and not a shell script? Maybe you can tweak it to change the path?

Comment: good point. you are correct, it is indeed a bash file and has a variable hardcoded, holding the path